# no provisional ios devices are available

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning

my Mac has Snow Leopard and Xcode about shows 4.2 (4c199)
An update came to my iphone4 and it has now ios5.1 (used to be ios5.01)

When I try to run on the ios device target the build goes through fine but the installation fails with "no provisional ios devices are available with a compatible ios version".

When I look in Xcode organizer I can see similarly:
The version of iOS on “XXXXXX’s iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.
and here is what the organizer shows:

OS Installed on XXXXX’s iPhone
5.1 (9B176)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2 (8C134)
4.2

What is the meaning of "Latest" here?
I hope I do not need to install Xcode 4.3 as it will require moving to Mountain Lion in the middle of the project?

Prior to this update the things used to work, I think (lately I was working only in the simulator, but before that everything work on the iphone ok).
Thanks for any help in advance.
Regards,
Victor

Comment: How do you came to the conclusion that you have to switch to mountain lion if you use 4.3? Just update. You have the SDK for iOS 5.0, which won't work with 5.1. It was always like this for iOS. If you don't want to update Xcode and the SDK don't update iOS on the device.

Comment: I'm sure the error said "provisioned", not "provisional". They mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was updating your iphone to IOS 5.1, because your current version of xcode doesn't support it. So basically, you either have to downgrade your IOS device to 5.0 or you have to upgrade to Lion(not mountain lion) and then install the latest version of xcode which does supports IOS 5.1.

Downgrading can be a bitch btw, so I think lion is your best bet. Ill have to do the same soon. Hope this made things a little more clear! Best of luck man!